# Why redis max expired keys is the maximum written keys of per second divided by 4

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

Why redis max expired keys is the maximum written keys of per second divided by 4.

The redis cycle deletion strategy is based on probability.I think even if the keys sampled each time are different, the maximum number of expired keys must be 1/4 of the total memory.

Why not give expired time sorting? Which is better than probability.I feel that based on probability is an unreliable solution.

I didn't find a reasonable explanation from books and official documents.
Official doucument: [How Redis expires keys](https://redis.io/commands/expire/#how-redis-expires-keys)

Comment: I have added official document in the question.